# How do I get the Google Analytics module settings to show up? I am unable to configure

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module and enabled it. But I am unable to configure the settings for it.

More specifically when I click on the configuration gear it just brings me to `Home/admin/config/system` and lists in this order: Site information - statistics - actions - backup and migrate - special menu items - cron.

In all the videos I have watched on installing this module. This page is where the Google Analytics settings tab should be.

I have also opened up the main configuration page and it brings this error message at the top. "One or more problems were detected with your Drupal installation. Check the status report for more information" It tells me Google analytics isn't configured yet. Then gives me a link to Google analytics settings. But when I click on it, it just brings me back to the page I mentioned above.

What do I do to get the Google Analytics settings tab showing up?

Comment: Have tried to use the flush all cache?

Answer (score 0):

The path is admin/config/system/googleanalytics

There is post about this on https://www.drupal.org/node/1510436

Comment number 17 states a fix

> But after uninstalling--> run cron--> clear caches--> reinstalling-->
>   run cron--> clear caches the configuration page appeared, voilà!

Also don't forget to run update.php afte you install a module en clear your caches